# Regular expression "\\d?" giving incorrect output

Tags: java, regex

## Sample code

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d?");
Matcher m = p.matcher("ab34ef");
boolean b = false;
while (m.find())
{
    System.out.print(m.start());// + m.group());
}
```

## Answer: 012456

But string total length is 6. So How m.start will give 6 in the output, as index starts
from 0.

Answer (score 3):

`\d?` matches zero or one character, so it starts beyond the last character of the string as well, as a zero-width match.

Note that your output is not in fact attained by `\d?`, but by `\d*`. You should change either one or the other to make the question self-consistent.

Answer (score 1):

`\d?` matches zero or one digit, which matches every digit, but also matches every character boundary.

Try matching *at least one* digit:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
```